# Interleaving reversing

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string, reverse it interleavingly. Here's how to do it for `abcdefghi` and `abcdefghij`, 0-indexed:

1. Separate the chars at even indices from the chars at odd indices:

   ```
   a c e g i
    b d f h

   a c e g i
    b d f h j
   ```
2. Reverse the chars at odd indices:

   ```
   a c e g i
    h f d b

   a c e g i
    j h f d b
   ```
3. Interleave into one string again:

   ```
   ahcfedgbi

   ajchefgdib
   ```

## Rules

- You must support both even-length and odd-length strings.
- 0-index-wise, you must reverse the chars at odd indices, not even.
- 1-index-wise, of course, you must reverse the chars at even indices, not odd.
- Input will consist of printable ASCII (code points 32-126), no newlines.
- You can take input either as a string or as a list of chars (NOT 1-char strings). E.g. `String`/`char[]` or `char*` are allowed, but `String[]`/`char[][]` or `char**` aren't.

## Test cases

```
Input
Output
```

```
Hello, World!
HdlroW ,olle!

Hello World!
H!llooW rlde

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
AZCXEVGTIRKPMNOLQJSHUFWDYB

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
 }"{$y&w(u*s,q.o0m2k4i6g8e:c<a>_@]B[DYFWHUJSLQNOPMRKTIVGXEZC\A^?`=b;d9f7h5j3l1n/p-r+t)v'x%z#|!~

P
P

AB
AB

xyz
xyz
```

For the empty string, return the empty string itself.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122367/8478)

Comment: I remember this being a type of "secret code" (kind of like Pig Latin) that we learned as kids in 80's or 90's, something to do with the word "fence" or something, but my memory's a bit fuzzy. My friends and I would use this to encode secret messages, and I don't think the adults that found our letters ever did figure them out...

Comment: @phyrfox you may be thinking of the [rail fence cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher), which is similar to this.

Comment: Ah I remember doing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
s2ZU2¦Z
```

This is a full program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19sFBVqdGhZ1P@Hu7ccbn/UtCby///EpOSU1LT0jEwuOCuLyyM1JydfRyE8vygnRRHCg3EcnZxdXN3cPTy9vH18/fwDAoOCQ0LDwiMio7i4ArgcA7gqKqsA)

#### How it works

```
s2ZU2¦Z  Main link. Argument: s (string)

s2       Split s into pairs.
  Z      Zip/tranpose, grouping characters by the parity of their indices.
     ¦   Sparse application:
   U         Upend; reverse both strings in the pair.
    2        Replace the second string with the reversed string.
      Z  Zip/transpose, interleaving the two strings.
```

Comment: That's exactly my solution byte-by-byte...

Comment: Alike minds think great. ;)

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
t2L)P5M(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19i5KMZYOqr8f@/emJSckpqWnpGpjoA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hfYuSjGWDqq/HfJeS/ukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqI6F4SP4Do6Obu4url7eHp5@/j6@QcEBgWHhIaFR0RGASUVFJWUVVTV1NU1NLW0dXT19A0MjYxNTM3MLSytrG1s7ewdcGuPjomNi09ITEpOSU1Lz8jMys7JzcsvKCwqLiktK6@orKquqa0DWhEAdgOQAAqpAwA).

#### Explanation

```
t     % Implicit input. Duplicate
      % STACK: 'abcdefghi', 'abcdefghi'
2L    % Push [2, 2, 1j]. This represents 2:2:end when used as an index
      % STACK: 'abcdefghi', 'abcdefghi', [2, 2, 1j]
)     % Get entries at those indices
      % STACK: 'abcdefghi', 'bdfh'
P     % Flip
      % STACK: 'abcdefghi', 'hfdb'
5M    % Push [2, 2, 1j] again
      % STACK: 'abcdefghi', 'hfdb', [2, 2, 1j]
(     % Write entries at those indices. Implicit display
      % STACK: 'ahcfedgbi'
```

Comment: So `2L` is "Push [2,2,1j]", and `5M` is "Push [2,2,1j] again"... And some people say that golfing languages are not readable!

Comment: @Leo :-D `2L` produces a predefined literal. `5M` is an automatic clipboard that stores inputs to recent function calls. It could actually be replaced by `2L` for the same byte count

Answer (score 7):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
/ZY
\IOR@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@68fFckV4@kf5KD//79Hak5Ovo5CeH5RTooiAA)

Half of the bytes of this program are spent on correctly formatting the source, the actual commands are just `IYRZO`, because Alice has just the right builtins for this task.

#### Explanation

As I said, the mirrors (`/\`), the newline and `@` are there just to make the ip move in the right direction and terminate the program at the end. The actual code, linearised, is the following:

```
IYRZO
I      Input a line
 Y     Unzip it into its even positions and its odd ones
  R    Reverse the odd positions
   Z   Zip it back again
    O  Output
```

Quite straightforward, I'd say.

Comment: If only I could grasp how mirrors work in corners...

Comment: @LuisMendo first you pass through the mirror, which makes you change from cardinal (horizontal/vertical) to ordinal (diagonal) mode or viceversa. Then if you are in cardinal mode you wrap to the other side of the line/column, while if you are in ordinal mode you bounce back against the corner. In this case the south-east mirror is encountered in ordinal mode, makes you switch to cardinal and wrap to the beginning of the second line, where another mirror makes you go back to ordinal and start moving towards north-east

Comment: Ah, so the bouncing is only in diagonal, in the same direction you came from. Then it's simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>108</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 93 bytes

*Saved 1 byte by using [@Neil's neat trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123083/41805) of using `s[s.length+~i|1]`*

```java
String f(char[]s){int a=s.length,b=0;String c="";for(;b<a;b++)c+=s[b%2<1?b:a+~b|1];return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFZV4JQFIWf8VdcKQsCSW0WycwGmwcrK6S6l0FRvNDloiniXydMXT71dvY6w/72Oh3Yh1nXM3HH6Ma6A30fVMIU41NIbT2uU2LjFrA4vQ2Jqvl8aGMKoOJLjolbtC0iJSfPh3SFZWXLJZyMSlBGgsDrguKrKFMo5cuoCIUJGuc1mZg0IBjochQzXoAcWwczM9B3bQP0oI252UVVG/EJCjO9OfeARWwOwKIdshDphmm12jYrLutOImqm47giaLjEMdILvZSV4@rJ6dl57eLy6vrm9u7@4bH@9PzSeH17T5og3WRXVjNr6xy/IYhZaTOXL2xt7@zu7R8U5ZJyWD76f11tNrWPz68lS9fpYdf7Jj4N@oOf4SgcR5PEY8r7xzwDn@OzEZ/kZepDn5o9yQ2o5CVJqYM5i4MSdavJFyqEwCHH87ycYqJUFP8C)

Comment: Java under 100 bytes...seems legit.

Comment: "_Java (OpenJDK **8**)_" Then why are you using a Java 7 method without recursion? Use a Java 8 lambda by replacing `String f(char[]s)` with `s->`.. And you can save a byte as well by putting the `int` initialization inside the for-loop: `for(int a=s.length,b=0;b<a;b++)`. [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/y8bb2a6v)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes (and a bug fix) thanks to pxeger</sup>

```python
s=bytearray(input())
s[1::2]=s[1::2][::-1]
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2qbIkNbGoKLFSIzOvoLREQ1OTqzja0MrKKNYWSkdbWekaxnIVFGXmlSgU//@v7pGak5OvoxCeX5SToqgOAA) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##dY9ZV4MwEIXf@RWpVQNKVXCP4r7Uva5VgWoooaTGgCFYcPvrmFM9xydfZua7c@65M2kp44TbVR33uzGJeiENQBWSCEQ6NpAGMicoJcFC4FIJil0LIdt3fruLUMPyNSCIzAUHWTWIKSPAUs7CoTzNpa5MqaBcgsKEHodmpBfGcKpgkzCWmKCdCBbWoPbDf7i5tb2zu7ffPDg8Oj45PWudX1xeXd@0b@/u1RLURuqjY@Me1I2JSbMxNT1j2bNz8wuLS8toZdVZW9/43@56fufhEQdd9Wgvpv0n9syT9EVkMn8dFOXb@8fnl4poDW9QRUnwGw)

Comment: 50 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2qbIkNbGoKLFSIzOvoLREQ1OTqzja0MrKKNYWSkdbWekaxnIVFGXmlSgU//@v7pGak5OvoxCeX5SToqgOAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: You don't seem to have actually updated the code in the post!

Comment: @pxeger happens ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b=a(x)=a(flip(x=2:2:end)))a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaiTZJuoUaEJJNJyMgs0KmyNrIysUvNSNDU1E63/J@YVa6h7pObk5CuE5xflpCiqa/4HAA)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>i%2?s[s.length+~i|1]:c)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḋm2U
m2żÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR1euUShXrtHRPYfb////n5iUnJKalp6RmQUA)

```
Ḋm2U Helper Link -> Dequeue (return last len-1 elements), take every second element, reverse
m2żÇ Main Link -> Take every second element, then interleave with the result of the helper link
```

<sup>*-1 byte thanks to Dennis*</sup>

Comment: If you replace `¢` with `Ç`, you don't need the `³` in the helper link.

Comment: @Dennis Oh what I thought I did that the first time >_> Nevermind, I must have screwed up something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <del>17</del> 13 bytes

```
O^$`(?<=\G.).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/jvH6eSoGFvYxvjrqep9/9/YlJySmpaekYmF5yVxeXo5Ozi6ubu4enl7ePr5x8QGBQcEhoWHhEZxaWgqKSsoqqmrqGppa2jq6dvYGhkbGJqZm5haWVtY2tn74Bbb3RMbFx8AsKa7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquqa2jqQK4AmAgA)

Fixed an error thanks to Neil.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Kobi.

Selects each letter preceded by an odd number of characters and reverses them. Does this by using `\G` which matches the end of the last match.

Comment: Last testcase is wrong. You'll need to use `$` instead of `#`.

Comment: @Neil Whoops, you're totally right. Fixed!

Comment: You can use `\G` instead on the lookbehind, and you can [remove the `$`](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#sort): [`O^\`(?<=\G.).`](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/jvH5egYW9jG@Oup6n3/39iUnJKalp6RiYXnJXF5ejk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vnHxAYFBwSGhYeERnFpaCopKyiqqauoamlraOrp29gaGRsYmpmbmFpZW1ja2fvgFtvdExsXHwCwprsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisqq6praOgA) (12 bytes)

Comment: @Kobi Thanks for the tips! But unfortunately it only seemed like I could remove the `$` since all of the inputs were in sorted lexicographical order. I've added a new test case that your code would fail on.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - Got it, good point. Guess it was just luck.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP>=7.1, 58 Bytes

```php
for(;$i<$l=strlen($a=$argn);$i++)echo$a[$i&1?-$i-$l%2:$i];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/079962836fdfa0b85b9c82a8e096e8c4fafc41b3)

Comment: perfect. OS says I have to type more, but those 7 chars say it all.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>14</strike> 13 bytes

12 bytes of code, +1 for the `-P` flag.

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
¬ë íU¬Åë w)c
```

### Explanation:

```
¬ë íU¬Åë w)c
¬                   Split the input into an array of chars
 ë                  Get every other char, starting at index 0
   í                Pair with:
    U¬                Input, split into a char array
      Å               .slice(1)
       ë              Get every other char
         w            Reverse
           c       Flatten
-P                 Join into a string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Caw6sVDq8NBdKtQFa5ZvL//0oeqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKSgq6AQA)

Comment: Hmm, `ë2,1` is rather ugly. I think you can do `ó o` instead, perhaps...

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah, I think `Åë` works too.

Comment: Oh, nice one :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

Requires `⎕IO←0` (default on many systems) for proper definition of odd and even.

```apl
⌽@{2|⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOevQ7VRjWPejc/6lz0qHdr7f//aQrqiUnJKalp6RmZ6lzIvCx1AA)

`⌽` reverse

`@` at the elements filtered by the mask result from applying the

`{` anonyomous function

`2|` the mod-2 of

`⍳` the indices of

`≢` the tally (length) of

`⍵` the argument

`}` on the argument

Comment: Was v16 even out when this question was posted?

Comment: @Zacharý It was in beta, but [it doesn't even matter anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).

Comment: Oh, so I suppose your gonna use v17 now?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 3 bytes

```
yṘY
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=y%E1%B9%98Y&inputs=Hello%20World!&header=&footer=)

Turns out by making my answer valid I saved a byte. Oh the irony

### Explained

```
yṘY
y      # un-interleave
 Ṙ     # reverse
  Y    # re-interleave
```

Comment: You don't need the flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

`ι` and `.ι` have been added since this challenge was posted, both of them save bytes here.

```
Sι`R.ιJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@NzOhCC9czu9/v/3SM3JyddRCM8vyklRBAA)

If we were allowed to take a list of string of length 1, [`` ι`R.ι ``](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M6EIL1zO///j1byUNJRUEoFETlwIh9E6IAIBRARDhcrgitJARGKSrEA) would work for 5 bytes.

```python
S         # split the string into a list of characters
 ι        # uninterleave: push [even indices, odd indices]
  `       # push both values seperately to the stack
   R      # reverse the odd indices
    .ι    # interleave the two lists
      J   # join into a string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 34 bytes

```
f a{a/=""a[::2]<>reverse(a[1::2])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P00hsTpR31ZJKTHaysoo1sauKLUstag4VSMx2hAkoFn7PzcxM6@aK9E2WikxKTklNS09I1NJB8HOAnI8UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUYXwE19HJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIKKKmgGKOkrKKqpq6hqaWto6unb2BoZGxiamZuYWllbWNrZ@@AW3t0TExsXHwCwi3ZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZVV1TW1dUA7QO4FuxnicKjzlWK5qtMUSqyjE7gSYmvT8osUShQy8xQSuWr/AwA)

#### Explanation

```
a/=""                    Convert the argument a into an array of length-1 strings
      <>                 Interleave
a[::2]                   Every even element of a with
        reverse(a[1::2]) Every odd element of a reversed
```

---

Here is an alternative solution at the same bytecount

#### <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
{[_/""]|_[::2]<>reverse(_1[1::2])}
```

This is an anonymous function that takes input as a string from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda s,j=''.join:j(map(j,zip(s[::2]+' ',s[1::2][::-1]+' ')))[:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQrJNlq66ul5WfmWeVpZGbWKCRpVOVWaBRHG1lZRSrra6grlMcbQhiAwV0DcEimpqa0SD2/4KizLwShTQN9cSk5JTUtPSMzCx1TS5MUaDgfwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 82 bytes

```
""<>(f=Flatten)[{#&@@#,Reverse@Last@#}&@f[Characters@#~Partition~UpTo@2,{2}],{2}]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/), 70 bytes

```ml
let f s=String.(mapi(fun i c->s.[(length s land-2-i-i)*(i mod 2)+i])s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy7DoJAFERr@YoL1a4CBa3BRCtKEgsKY7HsAy65sIbFRP15xDUWUk1mzslYKXqaZ9ITGHD5eRpxaFLWixsycx8AQSYHl14Y6aGZWnBAYlBJlmCCfMsQeqsg4zu8csf9DeOQBxvhnB6XYiASrTRaNTVGkC@tlkqbpsWI7/@1H@i@XifbpSqs12KhiWwMlR1Jhd4tFI22gtgS6XCtl14p1/Px5PclVuDxfHnySR7Mbw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
(_:r)!(a:s)=a:s!r
_!_=[]
f s=([' '|even$length s]++reverse s)!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyPeqkhTUSPRqljTFkgoFnHFK8bbRsdypSkU22pEqyuo16SWpeap5KTmpZdkKBTHamsXAQWKilMVijUVi//nJmbmKdgqpORzKQBBQWlJcEmRT56CikKaglJiUnJKalp6RqYSPsksbLIeQMfl6yiE5xflpCjiVIBH3tHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIKm2oFxRglZRVVNXUNTS1tHV09fQNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sH3OZFx8TExsUnIPyTnZObl19QWFRcUlpWXlFZVV1TW4fN0gDs7sYmCjRF6T8A) Usage: `f "some string"`.

For odd strings like `abcdefghi`, the function `f` passes the string and its reversal to the function `!`, which alternates taking chars from both strings. For even strings this does not work, and we need to append a dummy character first to get the offset right.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 69 bytes

```c
c,l;f(char*s){l=strlen(s);for(c=0;c<l;++c)putchar(s[c&1?l-l%2-c:c]);}
```

Pretty simple. Walks the string, printing either the current character or the opposite one.

#### Ungolfed and explained:

```c
f(char *str) {
    int len = strlen(str);      // Get the total length
    for(int c = 0; c<len; ++c)  // Loop over the string
        putchar(s[              // Print the char that is,
            c & 1               // if c is odd,
                ? l - l % 2 - c // c chars from the end (adjusting odd lengths),
                : c             // and at index c otherwise
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
DgÉi¶«}2ô.BøRćR‚˜øJ¶K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP8wNWFiMWX//0Rnw4lpwrbCq30yw7QuQsO4UsSHUuKAmsucw7hKwrZL//9hYmNkZWZnaGk)

I'm guessing the reason this wasn't done in 05AB1E yet is because it's gross...

Yet another time the `zip` function's auto-drop-last-element hurts instead of helps.

*P.S. If you have improvement suggestions on my answer, post your own; it's likely enough of an improvement to warrant you getting the points. I am pretty ashamed of this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ó oÔrí
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8yBv1HLt&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaSI)

```
ó oÔrí     :Implicit input of string
ó          :Uninterleave
  o        :Modify last element
   Ô       :  Reverse
    r      :Reduce by
     í     :  Interleaving
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x[w:&2!!#x]:x@|w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7oiutxKzUhRUbki1qrCoaa8VskjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VR6f9/AA)

**Examples:**

```
> {x[w:&2!!#x]:x@|w}"Hello, World!"
"HdlroW ,olle!"
> {x[w:&2!!#x]:x@|w}"Hello World!"
"H!llooW rlde"
```

**Explanation:**

Interpretted mostly right-to-left, find the odd-indices characters, reverse them and put them back into the string

```
{x[w:&2!!#x]:x@|w} / solution
{                } / lambda function with implicit parameter x
         #x        / count x,    #"Hello, World!" -> 13
        !          / til,        !13 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
      2!           / 2 modulo,   2!0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 -> 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
     &             / where true, @0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 -> 1 3 5 7 9 11
   w:              / store in variable w
               |w  / reverse w,  |1 3 5 7 9 11 -> 11 9 7 5 3 1
             x@    / index into x at these indices
 x[        ]:      / assign right to x at these indices
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 26 bytes

```
[:,@,./(0 1$~#)]`(|.@])/.]
```

#### ungolfed

```
[: ,@,./ (0 1 $~ #) ]`(|.@])/. ]
```

#### explanation

- `` (0 1$~#)]`(|.@])/.] `` Use Key `/.` to split the input into the even/odd groups: `(0 1$~#)` creates the group definition, by repeating 0 and 1 cyclically to the length of the input.  We use the gerundial form of Key for its main verb `` ]`(|.@]) ``, which applies the identity to the first group and reverses the second group: `(|.@])`.
- Now that we have the two groups, the odd one reversed, we just zip them together and flatten: `,@,./`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpJC4JAGEDv/oqvBVQYRrsKgvuejfsSQpBKxMCAXqu/boLg4V3ee@9lnEFVQIaV5a4gDWFJkOFy/p3E7iF8sNaJEu4WkTti4EdV4QHBV4Fx5rjh@WIwAu8NlDIEFZtof@AhNjB4PZ1YBYhROhz2kWyR7EI3TMt2XM8Pwuga30iSZnlRVnXTbqfemrVdurmfhmTtURJkXuFUVmMsfw)

Comment: 21 bytes with `(\:2|#\)({~/:)#\<.#\.` and 19 bytes with `[:,@,./]]`|./.~2|#\`

Comment: thanks miles.  is there a typo in the second one?  I'm getting [an error](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6OtdBx09PRjY2v09PXqjGqU/2tyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CukKahnpObk5Kv/BwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @miles also the first one: i understand how it parses and technically what's happening, but i'm not seeing the overall strategy.  can you clarify?

Comment: oh yes, it's supposed to be ``[:,@,./]]`|./.~2|#\``, the ticks got parsed out

Comment: 17 bytes with ``0,@|:]]`|./.~2|#\``

Comment: love that use of transpose.  i sort of feel at this point that specifying rank is a J code smell.  there always seems to be a way to avoid it....

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
^rI
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
     # Implicit input

^    # Uninterleave into two parts and push them separately to the stack
     #   "Hello, World!"  ->  "Hlo ol!", "el,Wrd"
     #   "ABCDEF"         ->  "ACE", "BDF"
     #   "P"              ->  "P", ""

 r   # Reverse the top of stack (second part from before)
     #   "Hello, World!"  ->  "Hlo ol!", "drW,le"
     #   "ABCDEF"         ->  "ACE", "FDB"
     #   "P"              ->  "P", ""

  I  # Interleave the two strings together
     #   "Hello, World!"  ->  "HdlroW ,olle!"
     #   "ABCDEF"         ->  "AFCDBE"
     #   "P"              ->  "P"

     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>93</s> 87 bytes

```
lambda s:"".join("".join(t)for t in zip(s[::2],reversed(s[1::2])))+("",s[-1])[len(s)%2]
```

Comment: Replace `reversed(s[1::2])` with `s[1::2][::-1]` to save 4 bytes

Comment: It comes down to 83 bytes and golfable, in the end: `f=lambda s,j="".join:j(j(t)for t in zip(s[::2],s[1::2][::-1]))+("",s[-1])[len(s)%2]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>63 58</s>  55 bytes

```perl6
{[~] .comb[{flat roundrobin (0,2...^*>=$_),[R,] 1,3...^*>=$_}]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dY9nVyoxEIa/51cERdyFsDTFsoL07r30XtwSYDFs1i0IIvx1buB48ZMnk3My75N5Z8axMFxFBUUEyw30KFTFMHbYDvYjKCh0KQ@2UyLZ0KSOrppU1nTIBVFYEISxNx5zT3g0qKMRDKHIWdqNdgdmlbCxZcMYJJqOLY4XZiY2uMCwEeAFk9rU5MK8CBzWvMn@icAgkg59pyIRTKn5Xe@PQ26o6YZjoyFeG1ixscrDLYBQs@BxWO4EeQT/UwRPCtgdJFlR8XQ214A0V6ZYnckaAGdxAaSFMmdPVZMBKGBCKIIdahLVBQoqMWkHIkoIdn3DM3OxhEGWYACSqXQmm8sXiqVy5eXP32qt3mi22p1urw@S/XQ32843i/VylaFKrdQotHKdTC8FAHRdXLqvPNcc7/UhvxAIhsKRm9vo3f3Do/gUiz8nfvcdDEfjyevPGm9kqVPj3bRsZ/Wx3nxuv3Z7AHcXW/fG88E5Xgu9CzS4DL/daNHZPX5UnqT4JDFKDTK9XKfQKjUqNeb/Ui83i@18N9tPD5Pj59eYLKoP07v57SJCQnrA8Js@m19dr68@L79cewCq7LDljwFY0@P9Bw)

```perl6
{[~] flat roundrobin .comb[{0,2...*},{$_-1-$_%2,*-2...*}]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dY/ZVuJAEIbv@ykaBUwgCYuKSwTZdx32HTFLB4JNOmZBMMKrMw3jOFdzuvqcrv/r@qvKtRFcJwRFBKstDCpERTB58Mb7KdSw5ECLuIZqEVk3oKCQlTz2olxcEITQjvP8Mz7G@2eBOBfi/2jT3YG6pB1kOzAJsW4gm2GFuYVMJjJpR1jBIg6xmDgrApf27dB/IjCxZMDwqUgEGrG@6/kUZCa6YboON0EbEykOUlnoAQh1Gx7nZE6Q5eBfysGTAnYHSVZUpM0XOpAWiobUuawD8CMugbRUFvSp6jIAZYQx4WCfWFj1gbKKLdKHHMEY@b7hD/PRhEKaIAAy2Vy@UCyVK9Va/en5V6PZane6vf5gOAKZUW5Q6JU6lVatQVG9WW2Xu8V@fpgFAPrOzv2B4AXDhsIcL0Sisfjl1XXi5vbuXnxIph7T//cdT6Yvs9d/a7zhlUHMd8t23PXHZvvpfe32AO7OPP82@MG4IZt7F0h0FX@70hPzW3SvPEipWXqaHeeHxX65W23Xm9T/qVXrVHqlQWGUm2ReHl@TsqjeaTeL6@UljhkRk7fCDru@2AQ@z798ewAa9NDljwFo0@P9DQ)

```perl6
{[~] flat roundrobin .comb[{0,2...*},{[R,] 1,3...^$_}]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dY/XduIwEIbv9RQiIcQGYVpCigOh9@zSe4mLDCbGclwIxDGvzgpONnu1ZzTn6J9P84/GsTDcJjmJB5s9DEhExjB1dCeHGVQ0wYYmcXTZJKKqQ04iG3HiRlGc47igh9xJG81gDCWonPsX3sw7UouMjS0bpqCm6thiWG5pYoOJTDsRljOJTUwmzvLAoUO79B0PDE3QYejcxAOFmN/94TRkpqpuODaa4p2BJRvLLHQBhKoFT59kzpBF8C9F8FwB3lEQJRkry5UKhJWkYHkpqgD8FNdAWEsrepVVEYAK1jSC4ICYmuwDFVkzyQAiomnY9w1/mI8KCqnAAGRz@UKxVK5Ua/XGy6/fzVa70@31B8PRGGTH@WGxX@5W2/UmRY1WrVPplQaFUQ4A6Lu49F8Frhk2GEJhLhKNxRM3t8m7@4dH/imVfs7833cync0Xr//WeNM2OjHeTct2th@7/af75R0A9C5c/z7wwThBC71zJLqJv92oyeU9fpSehPQiM8tNCqPSoNKrdRot6v/Srner/fKwOM5Ps/Pn15TIyw/K3ep2ndBiesQImyGb3V7vrj4vv3wHAJo06PKnA@jQU/4B)

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [~]                 # reduce using string concatenation operator

    flat              # make the following a flat list

    roundrobin        # grab one from each of the following 2 lists,
                      # repeat until both are empty

    .comb\            # split the input into graphemes (implicit method call)

    [                 # index into that sequence



      { 0, 2 ... * }, # code block producing every non-negative even number


      {               # code block producing reversed odd numbers
                      # (｢$_｣ here contains the number of available elements)

        [R,]          # reduce with reversed comma operator
                      # (shorter than ｢reverse｣)

        1, 3 ...^ $_  # odd numbers stopping before it gets
                      # to the number of input elements
      }


    ]
}
```

I had to use [`roundrobin`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/roundrobin) rather than [`zip`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/zip), because [`zip`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/zip) stops as soon as one of the input lists is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

takes as input a string

```
(s=Characters@#;Row@Riffle[s[[;; ;;2]],Reverse@s[[2;; ;;2]]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9r1Fs65yRWJSYXJJaVOygbB2UX@4QlJmWlpMaXRwdbW2tYG1tFBurE5RaBpRPdQCKGcEEYzXV/gcUZeaVKDikKTgoeaTm5OTrKITnF@WkKCr9BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

*Bytes golfed thanks to @Adám*

```apl
A⊣A[i]←⌽A[i←2×⍳⌊2÷⍨⍴A←⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPd6b/jo67FjtGZsY/aJjzq2QtkARlGh6c/6t38qKfL6PD2R70rHvVucQRJ902NBen578Sl7pGak5OvoxCeX5SToqjOBROBCQAA)

Comment: Are you going to explain your code?

Answer (score 0):

## GNU APL 1.2, 24 bytes

```
R[X]←⌽R[X←2×⍳⌊.5×⍴R←⍞]◊R
```

APL works from right to left. `⍴R←⍞` assigns user input to `R` and then evaluates its length. Halve this by multiplying by `.5` and apply `⌊` floor function. `⍳` returns all numbers from 1 to the argument.

APL operates on arrays, so `2×` the array we just got from `⍳` doubles each element, giving us just the even indices (1-indexed, so relies on `⎕IO` being 1).

When accessing multiple indices of a vector, APL gives the elements at those indices in a vector. `R[X←2×⍳⌊.5×⍴R←⍞]` gives just the even-indexed elements. `⌽` reverses the elements. Then, assign the reversed values back to the even indices (assigning these indices to `X` saves 6 bytes).

`◊` is the statement separator. After the reversing is done, evaluate `R` to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, <s>70</s> <s>56</s> <s>47</s> <s>38</s> <s>35</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x[w]:x(|)w:(&)#:[x]#0 1;x}
```

**Example:**

```
q){x[w]:x(|)w:(&)#:[x]#0 1;x}"Hello, World!"
"HdlroW ,olle!"
q){x[w]:x(|)w:(&)#:[x]#0 1;x}"Hello World!"
"H!llooW rlde"
```

**Explanation:**

Find the odd indices of the string, reverse this list, pull out elements at these points and then reassign them in-place to the original string.

```
{x[w]:x reverse w:where count[x]#0 1;x} / ungolfed
{                                   ; } / lambda function with two lines
                                 0 1    / the list (0;1)
                                #       / take
                        count[x]        / length of input
                  where                 / indices where this is > 0
                w:                      / save in variable w
        reverse                         / reverse this list
      x                                 / index into x at these points
     :                                  / assignment             
 x[w]                                   / assign x at indices with new values
                                     x  / return x
```

**Edits:**

- -9 bytes; switching out `count` for `(#:)`, `til` for `(!)`, `where` for `(&:)` and `reverse` for `(|:)`.
- -3 bytes; switching out `(#:)` for `(#)`, `(&:)` for `(&)` and `(|:)` for `(|)`
- -6 bytes; complete re-write
- -2 bytes; using assignment rather than apply

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 46 + 3 for -F flag = 49 bytes

```perl
while(++$x<@F){print$F[$x%2?$x-1:@F-$x-$#F%2]}
```

Uses the `-F` flag to auto split the input into an array of characters, `@F`. Loops through the array and outputs that element for an even index or that index (plus one for an odd length string) from the end for an odd input.

Takes input with a trailing newline. Without the trailing newline, can just change the pre-increment on `$x` to a post-increment.

A little more readable:

```perl
while(++$x<@F) { #While the index is less than the number of elements in the array. $x is 1-indexing the array despite the fact that perl is 0-indexed because it keeps us from having to use a proper for loop or a do-while loop
    if($x%2) { #If $x is odd
        print $F[$x-1] #Print the element
    } else {
        print $F[@F-$x-$#F%2] #Print from the end. $#F%2 fixes it for odd length strings    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
RDgÈúøvyNÉè?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/yCX9cMfhXYd3lFX6He48vML@///EpOSU1LT0jMwsAA)

```
RDgÈúøvyNÉè?   Implicit input: "abcdefghij"
R              Reverse the string: "jihgfedcba"
 DgÈú          Put (length is even?1:0) spaces in front of it " jihgfedcba"
     ø         Zip (reinjects the input implicitly): ["a ", "bj", "ci", ...]
      vy       For each element of the list
        NÉè    Extract&push element[iteration is odd?1:0] 
           ?   Print without newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 84 bytes

```
[_nwise(2)|[_nwise(1)]]|transpose|map(map(values))|.[1]|=reverse|[transpose[][]]|add
```

Expanded

```
   [_nwise(2)|[_nwise(1)]] # make list of two character lists
 | transpose               # convert to list of two lists of characters
 | map(map(values))        # discard null
 | .[1] |= reverse         # reverse second list
 | [transpose[][]]         # transpose back to two lists and flatten
 | add                     # convert back to string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5pU8IwEAbgvwL1apSixfvA@8AbT9QkYrRRi2ETkrR4RH@6tTgj3/ywM/vMu@/MtjqZV@NCyFKhIbWIigR@2dfa@sbm1vZObXdv/@Dw6Lh@cnp2fnHZuLq@IVAoEm9gcGh4xEejY6WgPD4RVianpmdm5@YXFpeqyyur/7cxIfS2ecfuHyL@@PQct15EG6TqaGOTtPv69v7hPr8I1HsfEMjtOaNEbH2PgIcwdRluQjc23K8g97eGiFJnNQOjpOGuzZTfm5SJhBuEXBmH1FU1T7nOY9y/xBTnRRZFWfYtlY0lmCwIIBEiiEElNodm3UAmNscP)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 27 bytes

Includes +5 for `-F lp`

```
perl -F -lpe 's/.\K./$F[@F%-2-pos]/g' <<< "abcdefghi"
```

If you give STDIN without newline you can drop the `l` option